# How do you make linked duplicates with modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, linked-data

How do I make a group of meshes which are a completely linked duplicate of each other? I’ve tried making a collection of the meshes I pant and made a linked duplicate of those, but when I change the modifiers in one the others stay the same, I can only change the mesh itself.

If anyone is familiar with Sketchup I’m basically looking for the equivalent of a component, where all changes made in the component are transfered to all other components.

Comment: It's not possible with linked-duplications, so you'd better use collection instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment you can give a modifier to a linked duplication but you won't be able to apply it (unless you make it a single object of course). So what you're looking for is probably ***Collecion Instance***.

Create Your object (or your objects), put it in a new collection:

[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Collection Instance* and choose the collection. By default it will appear where the original object is relatively to the world center, so move the instances away:

[image]

If you give your original object a modifier, they will all be affected, you can also apply the modifier:

[image]

If you ever need to make one of the instance independent, select and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Make Instances Real*, then *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data*.